# we have min-valuation?

Tags: valuation-theory

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Valuation.html

absolute value satisfy triangle inequality

$p$-adic valuation satisfy ultrametric inequality

$|x+y| ≤ \max\{|x|,|y|\}$

then can we find some valuation satisfy

$0≤|x|$

$|x|=0$ iff $x=0$

$|xy|=|x||y|$

$|x+y| ≤ \min\{|x|,|y|\}?$

is it exist? not trivial valuation.

Comment: If you take $y=0$ wouldn't you get $|x|=|x+0|\leq \min\{|x|,|0|\} = 0$? So it's the trivial valuation.

Comment: Wow thx bro XD i am stupid